# What is the function of app:endIconCheckable in XML file of Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Below I have given the code, Here I was not able to understand the point of the line with code **app:endIconCheckable**, because whatever I set its value (True/False) it isn't showing and difference, Can anyone help me out in understanding and when should I use it when not?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/foot"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="10"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/red_30k"
        app:helperText="@string/required"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/red_30k"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        **app:endIconCheckable="false"**
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@id/editTextNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Google's Android Docs did not provide much info: [https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does the same thing as [`setEndIconCheckable()` called from Java/Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setEndIconCheckable(boolean)):

> Sets the current end icon to be checkable or not.

> If the icon works just as a button and the fact that it's checked or not doesn't affect its behavior, such as the clear text end icon, calling this method is encouraged so that screen readers will not announce the icon's checked state.

I expect this to be used mostly if the drawable is a `StateListDrawable` and you have different artwork for the checked and normal states.

Comment: So,If i set Icon like clear text or something like that I should be setting `app:endIconCheckable = "False"`, Because i think in some other docs (not the [developer.android.com]) it says this method is by default is set to True.

Comment: And Thanks A Lot for helping

Comment: @Snehasisbasu: You should be setting it to be `true` if your icon is a `StateListDrawable` that has different artwork for the checked and normal states. For example, for password fields, you will often see this end icon have two states, representing plain and shrouded input (e.g., an eyeball and an eyeball with a slash).